# type changing in Java

Tags: java, types

Could anybody tell how to fix the problem at line 10?

```
public class TestString {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] tahed = new String[10];
        String x;
        x = tahed[0] = "P";
        System.out.println(x);
        String nimi = "Paul";
        String[] eraldatud = nimi.split(" ");
        System.out.println(nimi.charAt(0));
        if (x == nimi.charAt(0)) //10
            System.out.println("True");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add the Exception you are getting on this. That will help.

Comment: I don't know if this is your problem, but you are comparing "X" (a String) with character, using the ==, and in java.... I don't think that's going to fly.  When you compares Strings, you would use x.equals().  An "==" comparison isn't going to work.  It's like you are coding in C, but still doing it wrong (as then a String would be a char* and you'd do x[0] for the character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public class TestString {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] tahed = new String[10];
    String x;
    x = tahed[0] = "P";
    System.out.println(x);
    String nimi = "Paul";
    String[] eraldatud = nimi.split(" ");
    System.out.println(nimi.charAt(0));
    if (x.equals(Character.toString(nimi.charAt(0))) //10
        System.out.println("True");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to convert the char returned by charAt to a String. I like to do that by just concatenating it to a string like this:

```
if (x.equals(""+nimi.charAt(0)))
```

Comment: @OP `if (x.equals(""+nimi.charAt(0)))`  is the shortcut. if you want to do it the OO Style you have to do it like that: if(String.valueOf(nimi.charAt(0)).equals(x)). NOTE: the .equals() function checks for structural identity. == checks for reference identity. so if you do something like ObjectB = ObjectA.clone(); and then do a ObjectB == ObjectA then it will return false but ObjectB.equals(ObjectA) will return true.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to compare a String (`x`) with a char (`nimi.charAt(0)`).

Either you need to convert the `char` to a `String` (and compare using `.equals`:

```
if (x.equals("" + nimi.charAt(0)))
```

or you need to convert the string to a char:

```
if (x.charAt(0) == nimi.charAt(0))
```

(but that may not be what you're after, since your basically checking if `x` starts with the same character as `nimi`)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you define x as a String, but you are comparing it to a char value (the type returned by charAt()). Depending on what your intent is you need to compare them as two strings or two chars:

```
if(x.charAt(0) == nimi.charAt(0)) //do a character comparison
```

OR

```
if(x.equals(nimi.substring(0, 1)) //do a string comparison
```

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing string with char. It will never be equal. Try this:

```
 String[] tahed = new String[10];
        String x;
        x = tahed[0] = "P";
        System.out.println(x);
        String nimi = "Paul";
        String[] eraldatud = nimi.split(" ");
        System.out.println(nimi.charAt(0));
        char c = nimi.charAt(0);
        if (x.toCharArray()[0]==(c))//10
            System.out.println("True");
```

Please optimize code as necessary. This is just to put the point across.